# Connection refused on nginx docker container

Tags: macos, nginx, docker

I've installed [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) in macOS and I'm following Docker's simple tutorial on [deploying Nginx](https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/).

I've executed `docker run` and confirmed that my container has been created:

```
docker run --name mynginx1 -P -d nginx
docker ps
40001fc50719  nginx  "nginx -g 'daemon off"  23 minutes ago  Up 23 minutes  0.0.0.0:32770->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->443/tcp  mynginx1
```

however when I `curl http://localhost:32770`, I get a connection refused error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 32770: Connection refused
```

I'm struggling to see what I could have missed here. Is there an extra step I need to perform, in light of me being on macOS?

Comment: Check your nginx logs and/or increase verbosity.   If I remember right this is a nginx issue where nginx is trying to reverse dns lookup or something like that.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The issue is that your `DOCKER_HOST` is not set to localhost, you will need to use the IP address of your docker-machine, since you are using Docker Toolbox:

`docker-machine ip default` # should return your IP address.

See [Docker Toolbox Docs](http://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#access-container-ports) for more information.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks, Michael.

Comment: zsh: command not found: docker-machine

Answer (score 3):

```
docker-machine ip default
xxx.docker.machine.ip
```

Then

```
curl http://xxx.docker.machine.ip:32770
```

Answer (score 3):

If you on OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite or newer and using Docker for Mac, you will not have docker-machine or docker toolbox or DOCKER_HOST to worry about.

Just map the port on run command local-port:container-port

```
docker run --name my-web  -p 8080:80
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mac for versions above 10, you can try using "docker.for.mac.host.internal" instead of "localhost"

EDIT: docker.for.mac.host.internal is deprecated, they switched to host.docker.internal.
Reference: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: I believe its is docker.host.internal. Also, please provide a reference to the docs in answers like this