# How do I connect to a container hosted in Docker Toolbox?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-toolbox

I am attempting to run my ASP.NET Core 1.1 web API in a Docker container, but I cannot connect to the web API from a browser or `curl`.  To troubleshoot, I have also brought up standard nginx and Apache httpd containers and cannot connect to these either, so I believe this is a Docker/Docker Toolbox/configuration issue rather than a problem with my application.

I'll focus on what I have done with nginx and Apache:

I am running Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 Professional, and everything seems to work as I would expect.

- Docker commands all work as expected
- I can access the underlying Windows filesystem
- I can get the expected results from `curl http://localhost` (if I start the default IIS website on Windows 7)

So now I shut down IIS and run nginx in a container:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
45bb1f373c11b820d8431de3eb3bf222d57d412de53e8625f461b62c4279e644
```

Docker now shows nginx running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
45bb1f373c11        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   47 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   admiring_pike
```

But I cannot connect with either `curl` (within the Docker Toolbox command prompt) or a web browser in Windows:

```
$ curl http://localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

I get exactly the same results if I run an Apache 2.4 (httpd) container.

Any ideas?  Thanks! Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022250/connection-refused-on-nginx-docker-container).

Because Docker Toolbox is running on a lightweight Linux VM, it has its own IP address.  One needs either to map `localhost` to the VM using `DOCKER_HOST` ir access the VM via it's IP address, found using the command:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are running on VM, you need to follow this docker document from [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/).

After that run the following command to check the IP address of your VM.

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Start the nginx and hit [ip default address]:port in the browser. It works!