# Mongo DB using Docker Image

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-image

Operating System :- windows 10

I am using **Docker toolbox** and Install **MongoDB Image** on my local system.
Image installation done successfully.

[image]

after that I am using command `docker exec -it taxlien bash` to connect with mongo db and it connected successfully but I am unable to connect through our local using MongoDB Compass Community and also through our web application.

[image]

Comment: Does it works with command line? without connect inside the container but connect from your host to your container with the mongoDB cli

Comment: Thank you for you response, yes after executing shared command it will connect to database and through command line I am able to execute database.

Comment: Hi Aartek, can I make a suggestion about your question? Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing screenshots of the docker ps information, and the compass problem, it would be better if you could copy and paste or type the actual text into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Finally I got solution using cmd docker-machine ip default , I got IP address 
after that I will execute cmd

docker run -p :27017 --name test -d mongo:3.6

then i will connect with my local application and MongoDB commuinty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `docker-machine ip default`, and replace localhost by the result

See [How do I connect to a container hosted in Docker Toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585710/how-do-i-connect-to-a-container-hosted-in-docker-toolbox)

And check this doc https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories